# Why won't my solution add the reference to Excel?

Tags: excel, vb.net, excel-interop

I am attempting to add a reference to the Excel object library using the reference manager in my VB solution.  When I attempt to add the reference  nothing happens.  At this point my code breaks.  What am I missing on adding the reference?

This accounting form is called by clicking a button in another form.

Here is my code.

```
'Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class frmAccounting

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As _ System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        MsgBox("You are in button 1 in accounting", _ MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Accounting - Step before")

        'Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
        'Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook
        'Dim xlWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        'Dim range As Excel.Range
        'Dim rCnt As Integer
        'Dim cCnt As Integer
        'Dim Obj As Object

        'xlApp = New Excel.ApplicationClass
        'xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("\accountsreceivable.xlsx")
        'xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets("sheet1")

        'range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange

        'For rCnt = 1 To range.Rows.Count
            'For cCnt = 1 To range.Columns.Count
                'Obj = CType(range.Cells(rCnt, cCnt), Excel.Range)
                'MsgBox(Obj.value)
            'Next
        'Next

        'xlWorkBook.Close()
        'xlApp.Quit()

        'releaseObject(xlApp)
        'releaseObject(xlWorkBook)
        'releaseObject(xlWorkSheet)
        MsgBox("You are in button 1 in accounting", _ MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Accounting - Step after")

    End Sub
End class
```

Comment: Are you adding the Microsoft.OfficeInterop.Excel Reference to the project?

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/excel-vbnet

Comment: @codeMonger123 - I am attempting to add it using PROJECT -> Add Reference -> select from list of libraries available.  All steps appear to operate as expected but I do not see any reference in Class View -> References. The IMPORTS statement and code show errors. IMPORTS show no available explanation while the code shows expected "Type is not defined" errors

Comment: @Bugs-Thanks for cleaning my post up.  Am learning.

Comment: @codeMonger123-Thanks for the help.  Was able to load the reference when I choose both v12 & v5 options.  The v5 did not install but the v12 did.  Am off and running now.  Learning more and more.